# Replace a character or string in R

Tags: r, replace

Given this data frame

```
 a           b
1 --- rs149201999
2 22  rs146752890
3 --- rs139377059
4 --- rs188945759
5 22  rs6518357
6 --- rs62224609

df <- read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
text = "a           b
1 --- rs149201999
2 22  rs146752890
3 --- rs139377059
4 --- rs188945759
5 22  rs6518357
6 --- rs62224609")
```

I am trying to replace "---" in df with ""(empty) and "22" to "yes" with an output:

```
    a           b
1      rs149201999
2 yes  rs146752890
3      rs139377059
4      rs188945759
5 yes  rs6518357
6      rs62224609
```

I'd really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: If `df$a` only consists of "---" and "22", then I'd use `ifelse`. `df$a <- ifelse(df$a == "---", "", "yes")` But this only works if those are the two values.

Comment: `'Yes'[+(!!as.numeric(df$a))]`

Comment: @rawr I see what you did there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's as simple as you describe:

```
df$a <- ifelse(grepl("---", df$a), "", "yes")
```

Comment: I am guessing the output is from IMPUTE2 software, and it is always `---`, so we can do simply `ifelse(df$a=="---", "", "yes")`.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an approach using a lookup table.

```
vec <- c(`---` = "", `22` = "yes")
df$a <- vec[df$a]
#    a           b
#1     rs149201999
#2 yes rs146752890
#3     rs139377059
#4     rs188945759
#5 yes   rs6518357
#6      rs62224609
```

Comment: How would you extend this to other chromosomes?

Comment: @zx8754 I'm not sure I totally understand the question.  Is this getting at what you're asking:  `vec <- c(\`---\` = "", rep("yes", 23)); names(vec)[-1] <- 1:23; df$a <- vec[df$a]` (assuming 23 chromosomes)?

Answer (score 0):

use `sub()`.  Something like:

```
df$a <- sub("---", "", df$a)
```